# ¿Cual es el propósito de la funcion "setw" de la biblioteca iomanip en C++?

Tags: c++

Por ejemplo si lo uso en el estatuto:

```
i=3;
cout << setw(10) << i << endl;
```

¿Para que me serviría?

Comment: Echale un ojo a esto: [`setw(n)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw).

Answer (score 4):

Modifica la *anchura de campo* únicamente para la siguiente entrada o salida. Por defecto es 0, pero se expande cuanto sea necesario.

Veamoslo con cout, si quieres mostrar lo siguiente:

```
cout << "952";
```

La anchura de campo que necesita *cout* para mostrar ese número es de 3 carácteres. Así que a pesar de que por defecto la anchura de campo sea 0 se expande a 3.

**¿Para qué lo puedes usar?**
Lo puedes usar por ejemplo si quieres mostrar una tabla de números linea a linea pues lo normal es que se te quede así:

```
232 232
23455 13
123 1
```

Puedes usar setw para arreglar esto y que se vean los números bien uno encima de otro. Esto lo puedes hacer poniendo la anchura de campo a 5 antes de mostrar cada número. Para que quede mejor todavía también puedes poner dos espacios de por medio. Te quedaría entonces así:

```
  232    232
23455     13
  123      1
```

setw() solo es una de las opciones de formateo. Tienes más opciones de formateo. Por ejemplo si quieres puedes ajustar la alineación a la izquierda:

```
232    232
23455  13
123    1
```

Eso se activa utilizando `setf()`:

```
std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::adjustfield, std::ios_base::left);
```

En este caso y a diferencia de la anchura de campo el cambio si que es permanente.
Un saludo compañero :D