# Como alinear columnas de números en c++ (Matriz)

Tags: c++

tengo la duda si existe alguna manera de alinear columnas de números?. Estoy empezando a usar las matrices y me tope con ese problema.
Cuando ingreso números grandes , todo se desordena.

[image: Columnas desordenadas]

Estaría muy agradecido si alguien ayudara.

Comment: Mira a ver si esta respuesta te sirve: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/146605/cual-es-el-prop%C3%B3sito-de-la-funcion-setw-de-la-biblioteca-iomanip-en-c

Comment: Muchas gracias!!