# ¿Por que cuando mando a imprimir en consola salen los valores desordenados? C++

Tags: c++, consola, imprimir

tengo que hacer un programa que aplique el método de la bisección, sin embargo cuando tengo que mandar a imprimir los valores en una tabla me salen desordenados y no se por que
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es una parte del código:

```
            cout<<"n\tan\t\tbn\t\tpn\t\tf(pn)"<<endl;
            cout<<n<<"\t"<<an<<"\t\t"<<bn<<"\t\t"<<pn<<"\t\t"<<F(pn)<<endl;

            while(abs(F(pn))>TOL){
                n++;
                if(F(a)*F(pn)<0){
                    bn=pn;
                }
                else{
                    an=pn;
                }
                pn=(bn+an)/2;
                cout<<n<<"\t"<<an<<"\t\t"<<bn<<"\t\t"<<pn<<"\t\t"<<F(pn)<<endl;
            }
```

Todas las variables son tipo double

Comment: Es por el `\t` que estás poniendo. Ese comando lo que hace es tabular sobre el buffer incluyendo el carácter espacio. Lo que pasa es que (fijándonos en la primera y segunda columna), en la fila 10 tienes un número que tiene más dígitos (y por lo tanto más caracteres) que el número de la fila 9. Esto hace que el `\t` tabule el doble por así decirlo que lo que estás tabulando en los números de la fila 9. Una solución es ver cuántos dígitos vas a tener como máximo, y representar todos los números con los mismos dígitos, por lo que no tendrás unos números con más espacios que otros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como no proporcionaste un ejemplo mínimo reproducible, me fue algo complicado reproducirlo ya que a mi sí me alineaba bien las columnas. Finalmente dí con un ejemplo mínimo reproducible (al menos con C++ en VS2019 en Windows 10):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double n, an, bn, pn, zn;
    n = an = bn = pn = zn = 1.0;
    cout  << "n" << "\t" << "an" << "\t\t" << "bn" << "\t\t" << "pn" << "\t\t" << "f(pn)" << endl;
    cout << setprecision(10)  << n << "\t" << an << "\t\t" << bn << "\t\t" << pn << "\t\t" << zn << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        n += 0.000001;
        an += 0.001;
        bn += 0.1;
        pn += 1;
        zn += 10;

        cout << setprecision(10)  << n << "\t" << an << "\t\t" << bn << "\t\t" << pn << "\t\t" << zn << endl;
    }

}
```

Lo cual da como resultado lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una solución sería el uso de `setw` y `left`:

```cpp
    cout << setw(21) << left << "n" << "\t" << "an" << "\t\t" << "bn" << "\t\t" << "pn" << "\t\t" << "f(pn)" << endl;
    cout << setprecision(10) << setw(21) << left << n << "\t" << an << "\t\t" << bn << "\t\t" << pn << "\t\t" << zn << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        n += 0.000001;
        an += 0.001;
        bn += 0.1;
        pn += 1;
        zn += 10;

        cout << setprecision(10) << setw(21) << left << n << "\t" << an << "\t\t" << bn << "\t\t" << pn << "\t\t" << zn << endl;
    }
```

Y el resultado es que se modifica la anchura de campo y se alínea a la izquierda:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El `setw(21)` se puede modificar. Aquí puedes encontrar más información acerca de [setw](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/146605/cual-es-el-prop%C3%B3sito-de-la-funcion-setw-de-la-biblioteca-iomanip-en-c)